# Multiple Abstract Classes creating clashes

Tags: django, django-models

I have two abstract base classes that create clashes:

```
class DateModel(models.Model):
        created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, 
                               related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_user")
        modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, 
                                related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_modified_user")
        class Meta:
              abstract = True

class UUIDModel(DateModel):
         uuid = models.CharField(blank=True, editable=False, max_length=36,
                        unique=True, default=make_uuid)

         class Meta:
              abstract = True
```

With a normal model that inherits from UUID, clashes occur:

```
class ModelA(UUIDModel):
       ...
```

Error:

> product.ModelA: Accessor for field 'created_by' clashes with related
>   field 'User.product_ModelA_created_user'. Add a related_name argument
>   to the definition for 'created_by'. product.ModelA: Reverse query name
>   for field 'created_by' clashes with related field
>   'User.product_ModelA_created_user'. Add a related_name argument to the
>   definition for 'created_by'. product.ModelA: Accessor for field
>   'created_by' clashes with related field
>   'User.product_ModelA_created_user'. Add a related_name argument to the
>   definition for 'created_by'. product.ModelA: Reverse query name for
>   field 'created_by' clashes with related field
>   'User.product_ModelA_created_user'. Add a related_name argument to the
>   definition for 'created_by'. product.ModelA: Accessor for field
>   'modified_by' clashes with related field
>   'User.product_ModelA_modified_user'. Add a related_name argument to
>   the definition for 'modified_by'. product.ModelA: Reverse query name
>   for field 'modified_by' clashes with related field
>   'User.product_ModelA_modified_user'. Add a related_name argument to
>   the definition for 'modified_by'. product.ModelA: Accessor for field
>   'modified_by' clashes with related field
>   'User.product_ModelA_modified_user'. Add a related_name argument to
>   the definition for 'modified_by'. product.ModelA: Reverse query name
>   for field 'modified_by' clashes with related field
>   'User.product_ModelA_modified_user'. Add a related_name argument to
>   the definition for 'modified_by'.

How could I resolve these clashes?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing this problem too. :(

Comment: Ended up fixing it by doing a full check of the model. There was another part of the model that was inheriting the model twice and thus leading to a conflict. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've resolved too by adding this `related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_user")`. Thanks :-)